# Curly brackets in regexps with Perl

Tags: regex, perl

just trying to get my head around regexps. The following is part of the code. It read a file line by line and it has the following expression to trip the line of white spaces at either end.

**\A** match the start of the line
**\s+** one or more white spaces
**\z** match the end of the line

```
while (<$fh>) 
{
  s{\A\s+}{};
  s{\s+\z}{};
}
```

The part I am struggling with is the curly brackets. The only documentation I can find on them states they act as a multiplier.
I read **s{\A\s+}{};** if start of line AND white spaces replace with nothing, but that's my guess. I am looking to confirm that and what the curly brackets means in this regexps

Answer (score 6, accepted):

devnull has already given the correct answer, but I felt there was more to add than fits in a comment.

`s{}{}` is simply the `s///` substitution operator, but used with a different delimiter. You can use just about any character as delimiter, including balanced parentheses of different types, e.g. `s#foo#bar#`, `s[foo][bar]`.

You use this to avoid escaping delimiters in the matching string. Such as when matching paths:

```
s#/foo/bar/baz#/foo/baz/bax#
```

Looks better than the equivalent, using the default slash delimiter `/`:

```
s/\/foo\/bar\/baz/\/foo\/baz\/bax/
```

Which honestly is quite confusing.

In your case, there is no real reason to use a different delimiter, so the substitutions are in my opinion best written with the original delimiter:

```
s/\A\s+//
s/\s+\z//
```

Comment: I wonder if there's a similar solution when no substitutions are involved, like @array=/and.*?that's all/. If there's a `()` in the matching strings, it will not match.

Answer (score 2):

The `{}` refer to a pair of delimiters.

You might want to refer to [Quote and Quote-like Operators](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Regexp-Quote-Like-Operators).

```
 Customary Generic Meaning  Interpolates
            s{}{}  Substitution yes*
```

As an example:

```
$ echo foo 42 bar | perl -pe 's{42}{84}'
foo 84 bar
```